# Function for an Exp/Level Up System using exponential function with an average 700 exp/day and 1 year to get to level 100

Tags: functions, exponential-function

I'm working on a problem for my RPG I'm actually searching for an exponential function to create a level up system based on the exp you win I want to make it possible to get to lvl 100 in One year so 365 days with an average 700 exp/day, here's the one from Pokemon's First generation to give you an idea of what I search for :

[Pokemon's First Gen Level Up System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYaE2.png)

```
function nextLevel(level)
    return round((4 * (level ^ 3)) / 5)
end
```

So to get from lvl 1 to lvl 100 I need to farm for (700 x 365) 255500 exp
but I need to make it that it's easy to farm the first levels but it gets harder every level so the amount of exp to level up gets bigger and f(1) = 100

Comment: So basically you're asking to find an exponential function $f(x)$ so that $x=\text{level}$ and $f(x)$ is the required points to get to that level. And also we know that $f(100)=700\cdot 365 = 255~500$. Is this what you're asking? Perhaps we also assume $f(1)=1$. With these conditions, this problem is quite easy to solve. We just set
$$
f(x) = c \cdot a^x
$$
and solve for $c$ and $a$.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Not exactly it's f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + ... + f(100) = 700⋅365 = 255 500

Comment: So perhaps a bit of clarification is needed. Do you want
$$
f(x) = \text{experience points required to reach level}~n~\text{from the start of the game}
$$
or
$$
f(x) = \text{experience points required to reach level}~n~\text{starting from level}~n-1
$$?

Comment: I'm searching for :

f(x)=experience points required to reach level n starting from level n−1

Comment: Could you not just take $f(x) = g(x) - g(x - 1)$ where $g(x) = c \cdot a^x$ is the function mentioned by @MattiP.?

Comment: Note that Pokemon uses a power-law function ($x^3$), which doesn't increase the spacing between levels as quickly as an exponential function. You should probably try different experience curves to see which gives the right feel to the progression of levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want a function that has the following properties:

- Has the form $f(x)=c\cdot d^x$
- Initial condition $f(1)=100$
- Second condition: $f(1)+f(2) + \ldots +  f(100) = 255~500$

Solution:
From the second condition, we see that the left-hand side is a geometric sum. In general, a closed form is
$$
a+ar+ar^2 + ar^3 + \ldots +  ar^n = a\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}
$$
In this case, we discard the first term to get
$$
ar+ar^2 + ar^3 + \ldots +  ar^n = a\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}-a
$$
Therefore, the second condition is the same as this when $a = c$, $d=r$. The right-hand side is therefore
$$
c \frac{1-d^{101}}{1-d}-c = 255~500
$$
The initial condition gives us simply $c \cdot d = 100$.
A numerical solution yields the unique positive solution
$$
\begin{cases}
c \approx 95.264 \\
d \approx 1.0497
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it but as the initial condition I want to start with a 100 exp for level 1 (But THANK YOU SO MUCH for the answer)

Comment: Corrected to match $f(1)=100$.